# Django: Friendlier header for StackedInline for auto generated through model?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using a Django admin StackedInline, as follows:

```
class BookInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Book.subject.through
    verbose_name = 'Book'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Books with this subject'

class SubjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BookInline,
    ]
```

It all works, but the header is pretty ugly:

```
Books With This Subject
Book: Book_subject object
```

Anyone know how I can get rid of, or change, the `Book_subject object` part?

thanks!

Comment: The answer might be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086537/how-to-omit-object-name-from-djangos-tabularinline-admin-view

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've never used an m2m field like this, so thanks! Learned something new.

I found 2 ways to get around the problem:

1: simply reassign the `__unicode__` function with a new function

```
class MyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    MyModel.m2m.through.__unicode__ = lambda x: 'My New Unicode'
    model = MyModel.m2m.through
```

2: set up a [proxy model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for the m2m.through model and use that model instead

```
class MyThrough(MyModel.m2m.through):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "My New Unicode"

class MyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyThrough
```

Comment: Ah, both my `Book` and my `Subject` models already have a `__unicode__` method defined. However, this is using `Book.subject.through` (subject is a ManyToManyField on Book) so I don't think there's any unicode method to define. Any ideas how I can get round this?

Comment: I didn't even know you could do that with m2m, thanks! Yes, found a solution. updating

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the (admittedly now old) accepted answer did not work for me.

This modification, however, did change the header:

```
MyModel.field.through.__str__ = lambda x: 'New Title'
```

Where `field` is the ManyToMany field.